# Display check in comments

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to display last check-in comments in the site as an info. Each time every person by entering this page should see when last time checked-in this site and what was comments, who did it and which date. How can I do that?

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What do the check-in comments relate to?  Is it a page that is being checked out>edited>checked in?

If you are referring to Document Libraries, there is a field which appears when you configure the Doc Library to 'Require Check Out' for editing.  Sharepoint will create a 'Check In Comment' field, you can add this column to a View (see below picture).

[image: check in comments pic]

Comment: This is site where for example I'm doing check out and doing something then by clicking check-in I'm writing comments , so that what changes I did. Then as info I would like to see it in the same page, like who did last change ,which date and what changed ( statement from comments). How can I do that?

Comment: What is being edited?  Are you checking out and checking in a page?  Or a Document Library?  Or a List?

Comment: For example, a Document Library has a 'Check In Comment' field, which can be displayed in a View.  You can also look at the Document 'Version History' to see previous 'check-in comments'.

Comment: I'm checking out and checking in in the page. It's not a document library or a list.

Comment: This might help - using a Content Query Web Part.  I managed to make a Page show up inside the web part, but in the 10mins I attempted to get the 'Check In Comments' field to show up, I did not succeed.  That's not to say it is not possible though.  You might find you can achieve what you need through using a different type of web part otherwise, you'll need to experiment!

Comment: Thanks. I'm also looking for to solve this by coding. Can I do that by coding? If yes, then from where to start?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that with coding

Comment: Thanks Tally. Guys maybe someone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may check the function `getListItemByVersionPage` shared by [Shawn at github](https://github.com/pinch-perfect/development-samples/blob/master/Sample06/AppFiles/SiteAssets/js/SampleVersionDisp.js), the script get check in comments from version history page.

Update:
Copy the script here for reference.

```
function getListItemByVersionPage(listWebUrl, listId, listItemId, fieldName) {

            var glibvpdef = new jQuery.Deferred();

            var versionsUrl = listWebUrl + '/_layouts/versions.aspx?list=' + listId + '&ID=' + listItemId;

            jQuery.get(versionsUrl)
             .done(function (data) {

                 var entries = [];
                 var versionList = $(data).find('table.ms-settingsframe');
                 if (typeof (versionList) !== typeof (undefined) && versionList !== null) {

                     versionList.find('tbody > tr').each(function (i, trval) {
                         // pulls every 2 rows
                         if (i > 0 && (i - 1) % 2 == 0) {
                             try {
                                 var verRow = $(this); //get version row
                                 var versionLabel = verRow.find('td:first').html().trim();
                                 var versionDateElement = verRow.find('table[ctxname=\"ctxVer\"] a'); // Date for modification
                                 var versionUserElement = verRow.find('.ms-imnSpan a:nth-child(2)'); // User for Modification
                                 if (versionLabel !== ""
                                     && (versionDateElement !== null && versionDateElement.length > 0)
                                     && (versionUserElement !== null && versionUserElement.length > 0)) {
                                     var versionDate = versionDateElement.html().trim();
                                     var versionUser = versionUserElement.html().trim();

                                     var propsRow = verRow.next(); //get properties row
                                     var properties = propsRow.find("table[role=\"presentation\"] tr").map(function (index, val) {

                                         var trproperty = jQuery(val);
                                         if (val.id.indexOf(fieldName) !== -1) {
                                             var entryProperties = {
                                                 id: val.id,
                                                 title: trproperty.find("td:first").html().trim(),
                                                 FieldValue: trproperty.find("td:nth-child(2)").html().trim()
                                             };
                                             return (entryProperties);
                                         }
                                     });
                                     var entry = {
                                         Label: versionLabel,
                                         Modified: versionDate,
                                         Editor: versionUser,
                                         vprops: properties
                                     };
                                     entries.push(entry);
                                 }
                             } catch (error) {
                                 console.log("parse error " + error.message);
                             }
                         }
                     });
                 }
                 glibvpdef.resolve(entries);
             })
            .fail(function (sender, args) {
                glibvpdef.reject(sender, args);
            });

            return glibvpdef.promise();
        }
```

Comment: can you also include some details from the link. Like the function which provide solution or some description. Link only answers will not help because they may break and may get closed.